# GWT: Problem with application's architecture

Tags: java, gwt, architecture

I'm in little trouble with designing GWT application. I am trying to develope RIA app (with just one main widget, lets call it Main). First, user must be logged. Here's my way to do that, but it does have a problem, you'll see.

1. Show login components on root panel
2. If login was successfull (checks database), show Main widget
3. Widget is added to root panel

Everything works, but when you press **Refresh** it shows again login components ... It all happens in `onModuleLoad` method.

How should I redesign this logic? I'd like to let user logged (that means RootPanel will hold Main widget) for certain amount of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ

> **How to remember logins**
>
> Our login
>   system so far misses a useful feature:
>   For now it requires users to log in
>   again every time.
>
> We can use Cookies to allow the user's
>   web browser to 'remember' the login.
>   In GWT, to set the cookie (which you'd
>   do right after your GWT code receives
>   the response as we did in the previous
>   code fragment):
>
> ```
> String sessionID = /*(Get sessionID from server's response to your login request.)*/;
> final long DURATION = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14; //duration remembering login. 2 weeks in this example.
> Date expires = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + DURATION);
> Cookies.setCookie("sid", sessionID, expires, null, "/", false);
> ```
>
> Now you can run the following code
>   right after your !EntryPoint begins
>   execution:
>
> ```
> String sessionID = Cookies.getCookie("sid");
> if ( sessionID != null ) checkWithServerIfSessionIdIsStillLegal();
> else displayLoginBox();
> ```
>
> Remember - you must never rely on the sessionID
>   sent to your server in the cookie
>   header ; look only at the sessionID
>   that your GWT app sends explicitly in
>   the payload of messages to your
>   server.

I'm not sure what how your GWT app implemented communication with the login service, but if you want to see another example, I followed the example here:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine.html#user

While it uses the Google App Engine as the backend authentication service, I think it's generic enough to be adapted to any server that supports the GWT RPC server side and has authentication services.

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of server-side support to do it.

For example, when user logs in, mark it in the server-side session. In `onModuleLoad()`, call the server to check whether user is logged in before showing the login form.

Other problems related to pressing Refresh can be solved with [history tokens](http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html).

Comment: Can you please specify some kind of server-side support? Something GWT based f.e?